# initialise time of animation svg not to 0s

Tags: javascript, animation, time, svg

I want to declare an animation SVG, exemple:  begin X at 100, finish at 300 in 10 seconds.

```
<animateMotion path="M100,0 L300,0" dur="10s" begin="0s" />
```

But now, I want to initialize the start of animation like X seconds (here for exemple: 5sec) are already past. So I want the anim realy start at 200 and finish at 300 in 5 seconds.

Exactly what setCurrentTime() does, but works only on all svg (and so, all animations). I need to set each animations with different dynamic values.

How can I initialise the animation not to begin but like X seconds already past?

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to call [beginElementAt](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#__smil__ElementTimeControl__beginElementAt) on the animation element. That creates a begin instance time for the current time plus the specified offset.

If you want the animation to act as if it has already begun then pass a negative number.

Comment: I try to use beginElementAt(X), but just add a delay of Xseconds before play animation. It's not what I want. I want play at 0 second my anim, but I want they play like 5 second are past.

Comment: I'm sry but I have a new problem with this trick: if I use elt.beginElementAt(-5) on animation with dur="10s", it's works, BUT if at end of animation (i.e. at 5 seconds after launch "elt.beginElementAt(-5)" cmd) I want to triger it again, It's dont works! I have to wait the "truth" duration (10s in this exemple), to  be abble to restart animation. Nothing happen if I try between 5s and 10s after my firt "elt.beginElementAt(-5)" command... So, How reset the timer?

Comment: If you have a new problem, ask a new question.

Comment: It's linked... but if you want^^ If you have an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494010/how-reset-timer-of-svg-animation-when-using-beginelementat